# I want to validate if the created topic name is in the specified format like [a-z]*_[1-2]* in kafka when creating in terminal, how to achieve this?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-topic

`bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic topic name --bootstrap-server localhost:9092`
in here, I wanted to check if the topic name is in the format -[a-z]*_[0-9]*.
Example: topic name - demo_123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kafka-topics.sh` is just a wrapper to the class `kafka.admin.TopicCommand`. I don't think you can pass any parameter to `kafka-topics.sh` to achieve what you want, but you can create your own `kafka-topics.sh` that parses the arguments and checks the topic argument format. Something along these lines:

Note that if it supports short args or `--topic=topic_name` you'll need to account for these in the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

while :; do
  case $1 in
    --topic)
      if [[ ! $2 =~ ^[a-z]+_[0-9]+$ ]]; then
        echo "Invalid format for topic $2"
        exit 1
      fi
      break
      ;;
    *)
      break
  esac
done

exec $(dirname $0)/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.admin.TopicCommand "$@"
```